# Grails 2 with spring security: defaultFailureUrl not working

Tags: grails, authentication, spring-security

I'm playing around with the grails 2 framework in addition with the spring-security-plugin.

I built a custom login form, which should be always visible on the main page.

Thus, the user should always be redirected to the main page. Regardless of whether an error occurs or not.

In the case of a successful login everything works very well, but in the case of an error the flash scope is lost during the redirect. So I can't display the reason for the failed authentication.

According to the documentation, only the parameter 'defaultFailureUrl' should be adjusted.
But this doesn't work as expected.

Are there any other parameters necessary to achieve this functionality?

My Config.groovy

```
// Added by the Spring Security Core plugin:
grails.plugin.springsecurity.successHandler.defaultTargetUrl="/"
grails.plugin.springsecurity.successHandler.alwaysUseDefault=true
grails.plugin.springsecurity.failureHandler.defaultFailureUrl = '/'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.auth.loginFormUrl = '/'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.logout.postOnly = false // Logout through direct link
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.userDomainClassName = 'de.msg.login.User'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.authorityJoinClassName = 'de.msg.login.UserRole'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.authority.className = 'de.msg.login.Role'
```

I hope someone can figure out a solution ;)

Comment: I got a solution on my own. The flash.messages alway got lost, so I had to override the LoginController's authFail() method. Instead of redirecting I use now a forward to my controller. In my controller I redirect then to the main page of my application.

Answer (score 0):

As I understood you want to show the message on same login page after submit the login page.

Use this property probably it will work :
    set this in config.groovy

```
failureHandler.useForward=false
```

[See this link](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/urlProperties.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I think the property mentioned above is 'false' by default.